# Eevee rendering noise with MToon transparent material

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency, shader-nodes, noise-reduction, toon-shading

Blender 3.1.2

I have a VRM model I've imported into Blender. Both in the viewfinder and rendering view the glasses of the model have distinct noise. It is not a texture issue, the texture file does not have this noise.

I cannot find any additional documentation on MToon besides these links and they haven't shed any light on this subject. Additionally I have to use Eevee in order to get proper shadowing.

[Virtualcast Unity MToon Reference](https://virtualcast.jp/wiki/en/unity/shader/mtoonreference)

[UniVrm MToon Reference](https://vrm.dev/en/univrm/shaders/shader_mtoon)

Photo Attached for example.

[image: NoiseArtifacting and MToon setup]
[image: Eevee Settings 1]
[image: Eevee settings 2]

Im fairly new to 3d modeling, but willing to learn and research if someone can point me in the right direction. I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem has to do with how EEVEE handles transparency - I'm guessing the material's *Blend Mode* is set to *Alpha-Hashed* (can look noisy for some materials). Go to the material properties for the glass, and change the *Blend Mode* to *Alpha-Blend*:

[image: Blend]

NOTE - The noise on the glass in the image is because I had the *Blend Mode* set to *Alpha-Hashed* for the screenshot (to demonstrate the similarity). The window also has "raindrops" on it - disregard them, as the example is from a previous project - just know they are not part of the "noise" I am trying to demonstrate in the image.